# Mongodb C# driver update array element

Tags: c#, mongodb

I can't seem to figure out the exact set of statements that are needed to update an entire element of an array.  This is what I have currently:

```
//id, gameId, updatedGame passed in
var client = mongoContext.Clients.FindOne( Query<Client>.EQ(x => x.Id, id));
var index = client.Games.FindIndex(x => x.Id == gamedId);
var update = Update<Client>.Set(x => x.Games[index], updatedGame);
var query = Query<Client>.EQ(x => x.Id, client.Id);
mongoContext.Clients.Update(query, update);
mongoContext.Clients.Save(client);
```

I can do this in javascript, but unfortunately I'm working in C# at the moment.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I was not getting any error.  It just silently failed.

Answer (score 1):

The `Update()` statement you are using is more suited for bulk updates. In this case you only need to update one record so all you need is the `Save()` function. Also, without knowing the code behind `mongoContext` there are only certain things we can help with. Your object looks like it was adopted as a mixture between EF Code First and the mongo syntax. Anyway, here is how I've accomplished something very simular:

```
MongoCollection<Reported> collection = GetCollection();
Reported report = collection.FindOneById(Id);
report.IsReviewed = true;
collection.Save(report);
```

By using the `FindOneById()` function mongo returns a copy of your object with it's `ObjectId`. Which means all subsequent changes to that object will be updated when you pass it back to the `Save()` function. In your case, changing your array value would be done in where I set `report.IsReviewed = true;`

Comment: That did work.  I just updated the actual array element.